# Library or quality tutorial for displaying a graphical user interface (gui) for java. For a texas Hold em game

Tags: java, user-interface

So I have an array of cards. These cards consist of numbers 0-51. Is there a way that I can write Java code that can look at the number and load up a specific image. I dont mind writing 52 if statemets but I would prefer not to. I also want to display some data like bets up on the screen. and such. (Even in dialog boxes). Just want to make this game look good. Variables I want to show in the GUI

```
/**
 * Global variables include the money inside of the pot Each players money
 * And the cards
 */
static int[] moneys;
static int userBet;
static int compBet;
static int pot;
static String userName;
// tells the ai what it did to adjust long term strategies V
static int[] aiInfo = {0, 0};
static int[] numberCards;
static int roundOfBets;
```

I just want it to look nice. Instead of `System.out.println("tons of data goes here");`
Is there good code. That allows a GUI that would have buttons and such. And would allow me to set a variable to a certain value when clicked. 
Here is the set up I am looking for
I just want general code or a library. The interface should look like this______________________________________________________
Dialog Box Your Money =this |____________________________________pot=this_______
Computer has this much money|___________________________________________________ Community Cards pics______________________________________________ _ _____________
My cards pictures___________typing box for money___________Question(yes or no answer)

Comment: here is an already made texas holdem GUI already made you just have to have eclipse and maven but i would suggest that if you are really interested in programming that you learn yourself https://code.google.com/p/texasholdem-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with Swing? Java has a whole library of components, known collectively as Swing, specifically aimed at making a GUI. [Oracle's Swing tutorial is here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing)

Using Swing you can do just about anything you want, including making windows, dialog boxes, pop-up boxes, etc. You can add buttons, labels, images (like your card images, for example), and tons of other stuff to any window you want.

You don't say if you're already using an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) or not, but if you get into Swing I'd strongly recommend it. Many here will (rightly) tell you to code by hand as much as you can, but coding Swing objects by hand can get daunting. With an IDE you can "drag and drop" buttons and other components into your windows and the IDE will write the code for you. If you really want to learn Java, though, you'll have to go poking through that auto-generated code to make sure you understand what it's doing. Very soon, you'll likely run across something you don't understand. When that happens look it up. If you can't find a good answer come here and ask.

As for your array of cards, 52 if statements isn't going to be efficient or easy to maintain. You'd likely want to use some kind of loop to "find" the right card, then perform whatever action (display image, for example) you want.

**EDIT**: The NetBeans User Guide is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/toc.htm). It probably includes a lot of features you won't need to worry about right away, but if you want to know what NetBeans can really do, skim through it.

I should also point out that NetBeans is not the only IDE out there. For Java, Eclipse is the other major one I'm aware of. Once you get your feet wet it might be worth trying another IDE just to see which you like better.

Comment: Yeah I like to use net beans as my IDE. Does netbeans have drag and drop functionality. I am somewhat familiar with swing I didnt now that it did images too. THanks for helping me. I am thinking it will just name the file of the image the number. So i just say displayImage(numberCards[foo]);